# Understanding the behavior of EntityManager's merge operation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

Imagine simple "tree" JPA entity:

```
public class TreeItem {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentItem")
  private List<TreeItem> childItems;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"
  private TreeItem parentItem;
  @Column
  private String name;
}
```

Now one of these entities is being loaded, passed to web-tier, updated and passed back to EJB for save operation. What I've noticed it that during the `merge()` operation the whole tree is being loaded before issuing an `update` sql command, no matter how deep this entity is resided in the tree. Why is this happening? I cant see any reasons behind such behavior as I have no cascade options set.

**UPDATE:**
Yes, the entity passed back is detached and needs to sync its state with database layer, that's what I do understand. But what I do not understand, is why syncing requires reading the whole tree, disregarding the laziness of relationships.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Show code.  Generally speaking, if the entity passed to merge is detached yes its state is loaded from the database to make the new managed graph.  If you don't understand why that happens my guess is that you do not really understand the semantics of merge().  In the case of a detached object passed to merge(), merge returns you a newly instantiate object (graph) as the managed representation of the detached state.  That is why merge() has a return.  As for how much it loads, well that depends and like I said your question is not clear enough.

Comment: @Steve, thanks, I will update the question and yes - entity is detached, but I still do not understand why `merge` should eagerly load the whole tree doing even more queries than `em.find()`

Comment: You do realize that parentItem is NOT lazy right?

Comment: @SteveEbersole, yes, I do. Actually I expected read count depending on the depth of the level, caching on/off etc.

Comment: So, whenever you load a TreeItem, its parent has to be loaded; and its parent, and its parent...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the specification defines the merge operation:

The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as follows:

- If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a
  pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new managed copy X' of X is created.
- If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is
  created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity
  instance X'.
- If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown by the
  merge operation (or the transaction commit will fail).
- If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
  however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by
  relationships from X if these relationships have been annotated with
  the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL annotation.
- For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the
  cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL, Y is merged
  recursively as Y'. For all such Y refer- enced by X, X' is set to
  reference Y'. (Note that if X is managed then X is the same object as
  X'.)
- If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y,
  where cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL is not specified, then navigation
  of the same association from X' yields a reference to a managed
  object Y' with the same persistent identity as Y.

The persistence provider must not merge fields marked LAZY that have not been fetched: it must ignore such fields when merging.

Any Version columns used by the entity must be checked by the persistence runtime implementation during the merge operation and/or at flush or commit time. In the absence of Version columns there is no additional version checking done by the persistence provider runtime during the merge operation.

Therefore unless the detached object you pass has the parentItem as a lazy reference or null, its state needs to be fetched from database to sync with the detached instance.